# How to "glue" one node to another in SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Let's say I have a table node. This node is moving horizontally through the scene like this

```
func newPlace() {
table.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width + 100, CGRectGetMidY (self.frame)
}
var moveTable = SKAction.moveToX(-50, duration: 1)
var placeTable = SKAction.runBlock(newPlace)
var moveAlong = SKAction.moveToX(-100, duration: 2)
var seq = SKAction.sequence([placeTable, moveAlong])
var repeatTable = SKAction.repeatActionForever(seq)
var sequenceTable = SKAction.sequence([ moveTable, placeTable, moveAlong, seq, repeatTable])
table.runAction(sequenceTable)
```

First of all, is there any other easier or shorter way to perform that type of endless spawning? But my main question is how to place a fruit on that table? 
It should be on random spot of a table, but not in the air. 
So I need somehow to glue that fruit to the table and make it's spot on a table random every time table appears. How to do that?

Comment: What is your action trying to do? I don't think you understand how actions are used.

Comment: For the 'glue' you could add the fruit as a child of the table.

Comment: @Fogmeister 
That's the part of a game. Hero should be able to jump on that table, but should avoid fruits on it. My action here is just spawning and moving the table. That's all

Comment: @ABakerSmith
but how? Could you provide example of code how to do it in my case?

Comment: Adding a child is as simple as `addChild(fruitNode)`. Regarding the rest of your question, could you please expand a little? What's the endless spawning you mention; spawning of what? Perhaps if you supplied some images of the current behaviour I could help more.

Comment: @ABakerSmith
isn't `addChild(fruitNode)` would make that node a child of the whole SKScene? I need it to be table child, right? About spawning: Think of a flappy bird for example. It has pipes that are coming from the right bound to the left endlessly. I want to implement the same, but instead of pipes I have tables with fruits. It's just a table node that comes from the right corner to the left and again and again. I don't have appropriate images to show yet :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To 'glue' the fruit to the table you should use the `addChild` method from [`SKNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/addChild:). For example:

```
table.addChild(fruit)
```

As for the random positioning, you'll firstly need to generate a random `CGFloat` within an interval:

```
func randomCGFloat(#min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let p = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
    return (max - min) * p + min
}
```

For Swift 2 the function would be

```
func randomCGFloat(min min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    // ... 
}
```

You can then use this to randomly position the fruit. It's important to bear in mind that the anchor point of an `SKSpriteNode` is `(0.5, 0.5)` by default and so the origin is in the middle of the table sprite.

For a random position on the x-axis, assuming the `anchorPoint` of both the table and fruit is `(0.5, 0.5)`, you could do:

```
let minX = (-table.size.width + fruit.size.width) / 2
let maxX = ( table.size.width - fruit.size.width) / 2
fruit.position.x = randomCGFloat(min: minX, max: maxX)
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I get it! One question: what's "s/n"
 in this example:  
`(-s.size.width + n.size.width)`?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to change the names of the variables from the project I was testing on - updated.

Comment: Thanks! But I can't say that it's working for me. I implemented your code but my fruit (which is a glass of milk for now) always appears on [that exact spot](http://i.imgur.com/lWSQhax.png) for some reason. I think the problem is in random method but I can't understand how to fix it.

Comment: I've tested the `randomCGFloat` function and it works fine. Perhaps the problem lies in the values of `minX` and `maxX`; I would suggest you check their values.

Comment: Well, the main problem is: glass is not moving. I tried to remove `/2` from minX and maxX. Glass is standing in the middle of a table, at `0.5` I assume. Looks like it's hardcoded there.

Comment: Ok, it works, my bad. But where should I put it if I want it to place a fruit before shows up onto the scene? If I put it in update, it changes position of a fruit every second and I need it to be changed only when it's in the `newPlace`. I tried if statement, it's not working with functions. Please help!

Comment: You could put in in with the method that creates the table? I don't have your code to look at so I can't say with absolute certainty, but that seems the logical place for my code.

Comment: well, I don't have a certain method. I'm thinking of a boolean checker of some kind. I tried to make `tableOnScene = false`, then in `func placeTable()` I made it `true`. And then I did `if tableOnScene {here is that piece of code: let minX, maxX, fruit.position,x}` but it's not working for me. Fruit randomly appears only the first time (I assume) and then stays  at that place.

Comment: If I was making this I'd have an `SKSpriteNode` subclass that represented the table. Then in an initialiser of the table class I'd setup the fruit on the table. Then, when you want to create a table in your game you make a table instance.